# Nesting Flexboxes in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm starting a website for a school project and I though it'd be nice to try out the Flexbox CSS layout.

But I'm having a little problem nesting them with my header, that contains a logo image and a nav bar. Here is the HTML:

```
<header id="logo-nav">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="mnml" id="logo">
  <nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#goals">Goals</a></li>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#schedules">Schedules</a></li>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#form">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

What I want to accomplish is to have a third part of the header for the logo and the rest for the navigation links. I though the best way to do that was to make the logo and the nav as boxes inside the header box, but I'd like to make the nav a parent box for the links to treat them as flexible boxes too. My CSS so far:

```
#logo-nav {
display: flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
flex-direction: row;
-moz-flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
flex:4;
-moz-flex:4;
-webkit-flex:4;
}

#navigation {
flex:6;
-moz-flex:6;
-webkit-flex:6;flex-direction: row;
-moz-flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
}

#navigation .nav-button {
flex:4;
-moz-flex:4;
-webkit-flex:4

}
```

But of course that's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: The nav buttons just don't behave like boxes. Have your tried it? No matter if I try it on Chrome or Firefox (latest versions in both), it just doesn't work.

Comment: How could I try?  You didn't provide a demo.  I shouldn't have to *try it* to figure out what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: I provided the code. I'm a begginer and no one is helping me with this in class. I don't know how to provide a demo.

Really, if you don't want to help, just don't bother answering useless responses. Thanks for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by *"It's not working"* you mean that the list items aren't flexing. This is because the `flex` shorthand only applies to flex items, which are children of a flex container. Since both the `ul` and its descendants are not children of a flex container, <strike>they retain their normal display values.</strike> they don't participate in a flex formatting context and are not affected by `flex`.

In order for `flex` to be applied, you'll need to declare the `ul` to be `display: flex;`

```
#navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6E6L6/7/

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/6E6L6/10/) is another approach (if you're concerned about vertically centering each link).

Comment: Thanks you very much. It's working now. BTW I see this jsFiddle is really useful to share code on-line, I'll surely be using it ;)